# What should I use for best performance as an Array type on scala.js?

Tags: scala.js

Scala has some special treatment for Arrays since they are backed by JVM's native arrays, which adds complexity to their use - in particular, a requirement to pass class manifests when used as generics. It also has a less performing `GenericArray` for use when passing those are not feasible. Now, scala.js does not run on JVM, so what happens to all this complexity? Are Arrays of primitive types store their values unboxed? Is `GenericArray` less performant than `Array`? What should I use for best performance as an Array type on scala.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scala.Array` emulates the features of JVM arrays in Scala.js. This means that they have all the same complexity, and that `GenericArray` is indeed slower. They store everything unboxed.

For the best performance in generic contexts, use `js.Array`. This does not need class tags, and doesn't have the generic array penalty. However, `Char`s are boxed, as is the case for any generic type.